# What to do to make orgmode faster?

Tags: org-mode

I have org-mode file with more than 10k lines of notes and traversing through the tree (just basic up/down movements) is very slow (to the point that it's unusable). What can i do to make it work faster?

I know i can split the big files into many smaller ones, but i want to have it encrypted (into *.org.gpg) and don't want to enter the password every time i open different file.

Thank you for help.

Comment: *don't want to enter the password every time i open different file* <-- you don't need to do this when you use a key chain that you unlock at login time.

Comment: @rekado: could you elaborate a little more on how to do that?

Comment: @Dan: there are many implementations of key chains / key rings. On Fedora I use gnome-keyring, which is configured to unlock the keyring (containing my GPG and SSH keys) on login.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`linum-mode` is also having a big impact on the speed of browsing orgmode files, so it's better not to use it.

Comment: This is better - when i set it to nil (global-linum-mode in my case) i can have whole tree visible (without content) and there are no lags. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Collapse **nothing**:

`#+STARTUP: showeverything`

Your file "will be fast" again.

Answer (score 1):

I know post already has an accepted answer, but thought this might still be helpful to some people. If the cause of your slowness is `global-linum-mode` but you don't want to lose the line numbering, replace `global-linum-mode` by `global-display-line-numbers-mode` (see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers). Requires Emacs 26 or higher.